# direct custom post query interferes with other queries on page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

In a previous question, I was struggling with how to get my custom post type(s) to show when performing standard category/tag queries, since by default Wordpress doesn't include CPT's in these queries.  After quite a bit of hunting I found the answer to be this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if($query->is_category() || $query->is_tag() || $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
     $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
     if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type; 
     else
        $post_type = array('post','my_custom_post_type'); 
     $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
     return $query;
  }
}
```

And, it works great... I can now assign categories/tags to my custom post types, and then query them and see the results.  HOWEVER, with this code in place, I now have an entirely new problem which ONLY happens when the above code is in place... if I now query or view my Custom Post Type directly (that is, not via a category/tag), then suddenly my standard query items on the page (such as, a category listing in the footer) go blank.

I'm not understanding how this is happening, since I am checking to assure `$query->is_main_query()`, so it seems the initial if statement would be false....

Do I now have to write another separate function so that when I query or view a custom post type directly, I can then allow standard post types to function on the same page??  Any help appreciated...

---

### UPDATE

Thanks for the comments, I have figured out why this is problematic:

When I had my initial solution (not shown in this post), everything worked great with basic queries from the standard and CPT - but as I progressed into multiple queries, I realized that in certain cases, such as pages with queries spread around, in main page, some in footer, suddenly I ran into a crossover effect - like my menu would disappear at times, etc.

So that's when the `&& $query->is_main_query()` was added (see full code above) - and of course it worked better then, because I was only applying this to the main query, thus avoiding menu/footer issues... or so I thought.

Since adding this new version of the code, all seemed well - until I queried my CPT 'DIRECTLY'... when I did this, one of my standard footer widgets (calling a simple category query) went blank.

As I started looking at this, I could see that in my initial IF query in the above code, it is performing an 'OR OR OR AND' - when technically, to keep this code to ONLY the main query, I would need to do something like '(( OR OR OR ) AND )' - or, wrap the entire function in in an `if ($query->is_main_query() {`

So, I went ahead and did this (see below)... and when I did it, that solved the 'Direct CPT' call problem - allowing me to now directly query a CPT without blowing up the footer query.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
if ($query->is_main_query()) {
if($query->is_category() || $query->is_tag() || $query->is_home() ) {
$post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
if($post_type)
    $post_type = $post_type; 
else
    $post_type = array('post','my_custom_post_type'); 
$query->set('post_type',$post_type);
return $query;
    }
      }
}
```

So, this seems great, right??  But, not so... because since my first version of this wasn't set up as I had intended, it was allowing my CPT to be added to the standard category/tag queries at times when NOT in the main_query... so now that I have officially filtered this so it can ONLY effect the main_query in all cases, my on-page Tab query calls are failing... (these are making calls to my CPT via category within jquery tabs on each page).

So my new question is:  given my SECOND version of code above, which allows me to incorporate my CPT into standard cat/tag queries, AND query my CPT directly, with no ill effect to other queries on the page - how do I now determine what query my TAB calls are making?  Because it is obviously not the main_query - and therefore, I now need to target those so that I can include my CPT, much like I have done for the main query?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you'd have this issue with this particular bit of code. a straight copy/paste into twenty twelve theme with an added custom post type works fine for me, additional queries on custom post type pages are not filtered.

Comment: Hi, greatly appreciate your thoughts on this... please note the update I added.

Comment: if you're doing custom queries on your pages, you can just explicitly set the post_type in those queries, no need for the filter.

Comment: Actually, those queries are being done by a plugin - so I plan to look into it further - I will do that and report back, thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Hi, yes, if I modify the plugin and make explicit call to my custom post type it is working - but surely there must be a way to allow the inclusion of my CPT for this via a function, so that standard cat and tag calls that are linked to my CPT can pull the CPT outside the main_query without modifying code - Evidently I need to learn how loops work and how to identify them so I can set up filters beyond just the main_query...

Comment: you can inspect the contents of `$query` to see what query vars are already set and modify the query based on that. something like: if not is main query and isset `$query->query_vars['tag']`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for wp_reset_query

You would insert this after your return.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if($query->is_category() || $query->is_tag() || $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
 $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
 if($post_type)
    $post_type = $post_type; 
 else
    $post_type = array('post','my_custom_post_type'); 
 $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
 return $query;
  }
wp_reset_query;
}
```

I really hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks much for your thoughts on this - while that doesn't solve the issue, it seems like it should probably be a part of this - but I have found some other things out and updated the main post...

Comment: wp_reset_query is for resetting the global query variables after doing a custom query, it's not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I used your first snippet of code and it helped me out a lot with the **Sahifa Theme**. Like you, my nav was disappearing on the custom post pages. After analyzing the code I realized that the following line:

```
$post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
```

Was not including the other standard posts & pages when it was on the post_type pages.

So I changed it to the following and it seems to include every type & kind of post everywhere, including the navigation.

```
$post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' || 'posts' && 'page' );
```

For any one else that stumbles here with the same issue, here is what I did to get it to work.

```
function query_post_type($query) {
if($query->is_category() || $query->is_post_type() || $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query()) {
$post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' || 'posts' && 'page' );
if($post_type)
$post_type = $post_type;
else
$post_type = array('post', 'business', 'nav_menu_item');
$query->set('post_type',$post_type);
return $query;
}
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
```

Thanks,